# How to load a custom image dataset as numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here, I am loading the MNIST dataset from keras and printing out the datatypes:

```
(train_images, _), (test_images, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
print(type(train_images))
print(type(test_images))
```

Instead of this, I want to load a custom dataset in a way to make it compatible with the rest of my code. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What would make using arrays incompatible with your code? You can already use arrays as input, or you can make your own `Dataset` from arrays.

Comment: I have an image dataset..

Comment: Images are loaded as arrays. There's no difference.

Comment: How can I load my dataset in TF as such?

Comment: [Either with `flow()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow) if you want to use `Dataset`, or just save them all in an array and use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory()` for loading your custom image dataset, split train/test set, resize image,...  if your dataset contains n sub-directories, one per class (for classification). You should read this [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images).
Another way, you can set data flow with `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()` and [flow_from_directory()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) to load your custom image dataset or use Djinn's answer.